# mongooseJS find returning all rows

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, find

On using mongoose find with a condition such as

```
var condition= $and:[{'Credentials.UserName' :  'param.uName'}, 
{'Credentials.Password' : 'param.Pwd'}]

Here param.uName and param.Pwd are actual values entered by the user, which is set within inverted comma programatically.
```

Its returning all records in the mongodb table.

On using

```
.findOne({condition},schema,(err,data){
res.send(data)
})
```

It always returns the first row everytime.

I am sure that am missing something. Where is it/What is it?

Am new to mongoose. Thanks in Advance.
Edward

Comment: Hi @EdwardVarghese , I am also facing the same issue will you please let me know if you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
mongooseObject.find({condition}, function(err, data) {
     if (err)
        handle the error
     else {
        data should be an array of all matches
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! One quick question

Comment: $and:[{'Credentials.UserName' :  'param.uName'}, 
{'Credentials.Password' : 'param.Pwd'}] and {'Credentials.UserName' :  'param.uName'}, {'Credentials.Password' : 'param.Pwd'}. What is the difference?

Comment: any links or references?

Comment: @EdwardVarghese You can find everything inside the official documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/, it is well written and to the point. Also, if my answer helped your question please do mark it accepted, thanks :)

Comment: Hi @EdwardVarghese , I am also facing the same issue will you please let me know if you found the solution.

Comment: Hi @Godfather, I used that mentioned logic initially it is returning all rows every time, where as If construct the query with associate array it is working but for me the problem with associate array is with $in. If you how to push the logic 'usernames:{$in:['x','y','z']} in associate array suggest me.